# Centered image and Text to the left pushing image

Tags: html, css, spacing

I would like to have the image centered and have text to the left of it. Everything I've tried it either puts the text below the image, above the image or it pushes the image more to the right the more I type. Can anyone help me? I am new to html and css.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: dashed blue;
  color: #ff0000;
  float: left;
}
.mainPicture {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=main.css>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <div>
    <span>  My name is asd asd. I am currently attending  </span>
    <img src="onlinePicture.jpg" alt="Picture of Me" class="mainPicture">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Set the width of the <span> to: 40%. this will make your screen look like: 40%span|30%img|40%margin

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS positioning should help you out.

Set the div to be `position: relative;` and then set the image to be `position: absolute;`. Then offset the image `left: 50%;` and counter the width of the image by removing half of it with `margin-left: -15%;`.

Example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: dashed blue;
  color: #ff0000;
  float: left;
}
.mainPicture {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=main.css>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <div>
    <span>  My name is asd asd. I am currently attending  </span>
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="Picture of Me" class="mainPicture">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    border: solid;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
div {
    /*text-align: center;*/
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
div > span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    color: #ff0000;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 35%;
    text-align: center;
}
div > span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 30%;
    border: none;
}
div > span:nth-child(2) img{    
     background: #ccc;
     width: 100%;    
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<div> 
<span>  My name is asd asd. I am currently attending</span>
<span><img src="http://mc-fc.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/124124124_mcfc.gif" alt="Picture of Me" class="mainPicture" /></span> 
</div>
```